# Initial extent size when converting to partitioned table

Tags: oracle, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning, oracle19c

Working in an Oracle 19c database on Linux x86/64 trying to convert non-partitioned table to partitioned table.

Since Oracle12, alter table modify partition has been available to convert non-partitioned tables to partitioned tables. I have a non-partitioned table that has the initial_extent size set to 544MB. This is way too large. The actual first extent is 8MB.

When I use the alter table modify partition, I end up with 90 partitions all with an initial extent of 544MB. this results in the tripling of the size of the table. Many partitions are 90% plus empty.

Question is this. How to set initial partition extent size to a reasonable value during this process?

Using alter table move to recreate the table with new storage is not really a useful step as some of these tables are terabyte plus in size. Perhaps I'm missing it but I can't find a way to change or specify the initial extent size. I can alter table move partition after the fact and rebuild all the indexes but that has the same issues as alter table move prior to the partitioning.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY
Partition by range (mydatecol)
interval ( NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH') )
(
partition p1308 values less than (to_date('01-SEP-2013','dd-mon-yyyy'))
)
-- Below line will raise "ORA-02203: INITIAL storage options not allowed"
-- storage( initial 1m)
UPDATE INDEXES ONLINE;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can specify the `storage` clause for each partition:

```
create table t (
  c1 int
) storage ( initial 10m );

insert into t 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 5
)
  select x from rws;
commit;

alter table t modify 
  partition by range ( c1 ) 
  interval ( 1 )  (
    partition p1 values less than ( 2 ) 
      storage ( initial 8k ),
    partition p2 values less than ( 3 ) 
      storage ( initial 64k ),
    partition p3 values less than ( 4 ) 
      storage ( initial 128k )
  );
  
select partition_name, initial_extent 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   INITIAL_EXTENT   
P1                        16384 
P2                        65536 
P3                       131072 
SYS_P42018             10485760 
SYS_P42019             10485760
```

Note you have to do this for all the partitions. The auto-created interval partitions will have the same initial as the original table. Any new partitions will also have this same initial size. You can change this with the `modify default attributes` clause:

```
insert into t values ( 6 );

alter table t modify 
  default attributes storage ( initial 16k );

insert into t values ( 7 );  
  
select partition_name, initial_extent 
from   user_tab_partitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME   INITIAL_EXTENT   
P1                        16384 
P2                        65536 
P3                       131072 
SYS_P42018             10485760 
SYS_P42019             10485760 
SYS_P42020             10485760 
SYS_P42021                16384
```

Comment: Interesting, this might work. requires all partitions to be noted in the modify command is the only drawback.

Comment: Correct; you could always write a script to generate alter table statement